# Undefined control sequence: \errhelp \@err@

Tags: tabularx

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[7pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=10mm,
 right=10mm,
 top=15mm,
 bottom=15mm
 }

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\definecolor{header-color}{HTML}{C0C0C0}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\chapter{Parameters List}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{\widthof{\bfseries Offset}}|l|l|X|}
    \hline\rowcolor{header-color}{\bfseries Offset} & {\bfseries Register Name} & {\bfseries HW Reset Value} & {\bfseries Description}\\\hline\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline\rowcolor{header-color}{\bfseries Offset} & {\bfseries Register Name} & {\bfseries HW Reset Value} & {\bfseries Description}\\\hline\hline
    \endhead

0x0000 & \hyperref[__LINK__0_0_1585206671]{REG\_NAME} & 0x0000000000000000* & General Configuration and Status register \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

For some reason I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...
                                                #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.42 \end{tabularx}
```

What could be wrong?
[Log file](https://pastebin.com/eDrEw0qN)

P.S. My table could be longer than 1 page

Comment: The code example compiles for me without error. I get a few warnings (```Package scrreprt Warning: You've used obsolete option `7pt'.```, `Package typearea Warning: DIV for 7.0pt and used papersize not defined!`, `Package typearea Warning: Very low DIV value!`, `Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.`, ```LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `__LINK__0_0_1585206671' on page 1 undefined```) but I certainly do not get the error you describe. Is that error message from the code shown in the question? (I'm asking because it mentions line 42, but the MWE only has 41 lines.)

Comment: Can you make sure the example reproduces the error and upload the complete `.log` file of the code you posted to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ (the full `.log` file will likely be too long for inclusion in the question).

Comment: Instead of ltablex, I'd suggest using xltabular. This package also allows you to have mid-table page breaks and X type columns.

Comment: `xltabular` give the same error

Comment: Mhhh, the `.log` shows that your TeX system is more than four years old, but other than that the error message unfortunately does not tell me a lot more. In case there is any doubt let me claridfy that with a current system the MWE produces no error and compiles as expected. Sadly I won't be able to investigate this matter any further, but maybe someone else has seen an error like this in the context before and has an idea. (It may be an `\edef` gone wrong, so `\protect` could help, but I have no idea which command needs protecting.)